# Does Dart main() function need to be void main() or can void type be omitted?

Tags: flutter, dart

As a complete beginner learning `Dart`, I want to *understand* if the `void` type is required for a `main` function. In the official language tour: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#a-basic-dart-program the examples do *not* include the `void` keyword/type. 
But in other places we seed `void main() {` ...

The following two snippets of code have the same output:

```dart
main() {
  print('Hello World!');
}
```

Runs fine on Dart Pad: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/fa6f6e5a7b9406e88b31a17e82655ef8 
(*we don't see any compiler warnings or advice suggesting the `void` should be added*)

```dart
void main() {
  print('Hello World!');
}
```

Is the **`void`** a convention that nobody questions or can we *exclude* it without any consequences?

**Note**: I'm aware of the history of `void` keyword/type, I just want to *understand* if I can safely *omit* the `void` from more advanced programs or if it's required.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_type
- https://medium.com/flutter-community/the-curious-case-of-void-in-dart-f0535705e529
- https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-legacy-of-the-void-e7afb5f44df0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Dart 2.2 language specification](https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.2.pdf) says:

> ### 18.4 Scripts
>
> A *script* is a library whose exported namespace (18.2) includes a top-level 
>   function declaration named `main` that has either zero, one or two required arguments.

The spec imposes requirements on the name and the arity (and types) of its arguments.  There is no requirement on its return type, so using a different type (such as `dynamic`, which is what it would be if you omit `void`) would have no effect.

Comment: Superb concise answer James, thanks for the link to the Spec!

Comment: Don't want to give this more attention that it needs... but is it maybe better to be explicit and then use void instead of leaving it "open" to a dynamic return?

Answer (score 2):

Declaring no type is identical to declaring `void`.

I'm not sure if Flutter/Dart want the `void` there for some sort of "identification" but I doubt it. If it runs, it should be 100% the same.

Comment: It's true that the return type doesn't matter, but declaring no return type is equivalent to using a return type of `dynamic`, which you can verify by inspecting the type in Dartpad or by running `main() { print(main.runtimeType); }`.

Answer (score 1):

The [Dart linter](https://github.com/dart-lang/linter) has the following rule:

`always_declare_return_types` ([ref](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/always_declare_return_types.html))

> DO declare method return types.
>
> When declaring a method or function always specify a return type. Declaring return types for functions helps improve your codebase by allowing the analyzer to more adequately check your code for errors that could occur during runtime.

**BAD:**

```
main() { }

_bar() => _Foo();

class _Foo {
  _foo() => 42;
}
```

**GOOD:**

```
void main() { }

_Foo _bar() => _Foo();

class _Foo {
  int _foo() => 42;
}
```